# Grunt change target based on input

Tags: gruntjs, command-line-interface

My Gruntfile is as follows:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  'use strict';

  var dictionary = {
      'all' : '**',
      'html5' : 'some/path'
  };

  require('time-grunt')(grunt);
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  grunt.initConfig({
      eslint : {
        options : {
          config : '.eslintrc'
        },
        target : ['hello/world/js/<HERE>/**.js']
      }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', 'Lint a set of files', function(set) {
    set = set || 'all';
    var path = dictionary[set];

    grunt.task.run('eslint');
  });
};
```

Notice the `<HERE>` in the code. That is where I want the `path` variable to be inserted. I just have no idea how to do this.

If I type `grunt test:html5`, the `path` variable is set to the correct path, so I got that working, now I just need to tell ESLint where to lint. But how?

***Edit:***
According to the accepted answer, I now have this, which works! I want to share it in case someone else might want to take a look.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  'use strict';

  var dictionary = {
      'webroot' : 'app/webroot/**',
      'html5' : 'app/webroot/js/some/path'
  };

  require('time-grunt')(grunt);
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  grunt.initConfig({
      eslint : {
        options : {
          config : '.eslintrc'
        },
        target : ['<%= path %>']
      }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', 'Lint a set of files', function(pathKey) {
    pathKey = pathKey || 'webroot';
    var path = (dictionary[pathKey] || pathKey) + '/*.js';
    console.log('Parsed path as', path);

    grunt.config.set('path', path);
    grunt.task.run('eslint');
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the value of your given path in the grunt config and refer to it:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  'use strict';

  var dictionary = {
      'all' : '**',
      'html5' : 'some/path'
  };

  require('time-grunt')(grunt);
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  grunt.initConfig({
      eslint : {
        options : {
          config : '.eslintrc'
        },
        target : ['hello/world/js/<%= dir %>/**.js']
      }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', 'Lint a set of files', function(pathKey) {
      var dir = dictionary[pathKey]
      grunt.config.set('dir', dir );

    grunt.task.run('eslint');
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [grunt.option](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.option) to pass arguments to the Gruntfile.

in the Gruntfile:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    eslint : {
      options : {
        config : '.eslintrc'
      },
      target : ['hello/world/js/<%= grunt.option('path') %>/**.js']
    }
});
```

from the CLI: `grunt test --path=foo` to get `'hello/world/js/foo/**.js'`.

Comment: I upvoted because the answer is clear and it works, but I chose the other answer over yours as I prefer the a:b input over a --c=b